# How to minimize a multivariate sympy function by casting it to a lambda function?

Tags: python, numpy, lambda, scipy, sympy

I'm trying to write a function that implements the 'effective variance method' of least squares regression. In this formula the derivative of a model needs to be used in the least squares sum. I was trying to write the function so that one could hand it a model written in sympy so that the function would automatically differentiate it to the correct variable, and give it to the scipy minimize function to minimize it in multiple variables.

I get many an error when trying this, such as:

"_lambdifygenerated() missing 1 required positional argument" when I try to use the simpy lambdify function, like:

```
A = sp.Function("A")
x, y = sp.symbols("x y")
A = 1 + x**2 + y**2
g = sp.lambdify([x, y], A, "numpy")
minimize(g, [1, 1])
```

and
"ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''" when I try to use sp.N to numerically evauate as far as simpy can the function I then return to the minimizer, in a manner similar to this (I suppose):

```
minimize(lambda t: sp.N((t + x).subs(x, sp.pi)), [1])
```

(which returns "'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'subs'" in this specific case, but the above error when implemented in my function).

Comment: I just edited your post. Be aware that [tag:simpy] and [tag:sympy] are different python packages.

Comment: `lambdify` translates a sympy expression into a python function. `lambda` is just a short way of writing a python function.  No translation.  In either case you need to understand what kind argument `minimize` is passing to it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `g` expects to receive two separate arguments, `x` and `y`, but `scipy.optimize.minimize` requires a callable that accepts a single array argument, say `z`. A simple solution is to create a new function `h` that accepts a single argument `z` and splits it into arguments `x` and `y` before calling `g(x, y)`. Then you can use `minimize` to optimize `h`.

```py
from sympy import symbols, lambdify
from scipy import optimize
x, y = symbols("x y")
A = 1 + x**2 + y**2
g = lambdify([x, y], A, "numpy")

# this is shorthand for
# def h(z):
#     x, y = z
#     return g(x, y)
# res = optimize.minimize(h, [1, 1])

res = optimize.minimize(lambda z: g(*z), [1, 1])
```